# Где нету запятой?

Tags: php

```
echo "<div id = 'statia'><div id = 'img'><img src = $record['img']></div><div id = 'title'>$record['title']</div><div id = 'text'></div></div>";
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in ... on line 38

Answer (score 2):

Если не хотите использовать конкатенацию можете поместить переменные в фигурные скобки `{$record['img']}` и `{$record['title']}`. Но это сработает только внутри двойных кавычек.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте точки для правильной конкатенации строк:

```
echo "<div id = 'statia'><div id = 'img'><img src = ".$record."['img']></div><div id = 'title'>".$record."['title']</div><div id = 'text'></div></div>";
```

Comment: Поправьте код. `$record` - массив